# Transformations with Data.Aeson.Lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

Using `aeson-lens`, I wrote this program that takes me very close to what I want to achieve:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Conduit ( simpleHttp )
import Data.Aeson           ( decode
                            , Value
                            )
import Data.Maybe           ( fromJust )
import Control.Lens         ( (^.) )
import Data.Aeson.Lens      ( key, nth )

main :: IO ()
main = do
  pageContents <- simpleHttp "http://127.0.0.1:28017/baseball/team/"
  let v = decode pageContents :: Maybe Value
  let totalRowsVal = v ^. key "total_rows" :: Maybe Int
      oidVal       = v ^. key "rows" . nth 0 ^. key "_id" ^. key "$oid" :: Maybe String
  print totalRowsVal
  print oidVal
  return ()
```

The JSON content is:

```
{
  "total_rows": 2,
  "rows": [
    {
      "_id": { "$oid": "5548ed2671eab385baadf0a7" },
      "abc": 123
    },
    {
      "_id": { "$oid": "5548ed5171eab385baadf0a8" },
      "def": 456
    }
  ],
  "query": {},
  "offset": 0,
  "millis": 0
}
```

The output is:

```
Just 2
Just "5548ed2671eab385baadf0a7"
```

I would like to get to a point where the output is:

```
Just 2
Just [("abc",123),("def",456)]
```

In other words, I would like to extract the useful contents from the value under the `rows` key without knowing in advance what the keys are in the elements of that JSON array.
I would also like the program to signal to the user that the value under the `query` key is an empty JSON object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First of all use `lens-aeson` not `aeson-lens`. `aeson-lens` hasn't been updated in a while and I don't think all its lenses are law-abiding.** Since they both share `Data.Aeson.Lens` you'll have to run `ghc-pkg unregister aeson-lens` (or `cabal sandbox hc-pkg unregister aeson-lens` if you're using a sandbox).

You haven't described exactly how you know what the "useful contents" are so I'm assuming it's anything not called `"_id"` and points to an integer. In `aeson-lens` each object of an array is a `HashMap` so first we'll make a traversal over those:

```
rows :: Traversal' Value (HM.HashMap Text Value)
rows = key "rows" . _Array . each . _Object
-- or  key "rows" . values
```

For the row values we can use indexed traversals, where the index is the `Text` of the `HashMap`. We can then filter the contents using `ifiltered` by checking the index isn't `"_id"`. We also use `_Integer` to only get things pointing to an `Integer`.

```
nonIds :: IndexedTraversal' Text (HM.HashMap Text Value)  Integer
nonIds = itraversed . ifiltered (\i _ -> i /= "_id") . _Integer
-- or    members . ifiltered (\i _ -> i /= "_id") . _Integer
```

From here it's easy to get a list of what you want:

```
> v ^@.. rows . nonIds
[("abc",123),("def",456)]
```

(`^@..`) returns a list of an indexed traversal, along with it's index.

To check "query" is an empty object you can use `nullOf`:

```
emptyQuery = nullOf (key "query" . _Object . each) v
```

Here's a working example (I saved the json file to "json.json":

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB
import Control.Lens

main :: IO ()
main = do
  contents <- LB.readFile "json.json"
  let Just v = decode contents :: Maybe Value
  let totalRows  = v ^? key "total_rows" . _Integer
      rows       = key "rows" . values
      nonIds     = members . ifiltered (\i _ -> i /= "_id") . _Integer
      vals       = v ^@.. rows . nonIds
      emptyQuery = nullOf (key "query" . members) v
  print totalRows
  print vals
  print emptyQuery
```

which gives the output

```
Just 2
[("abc",123),("def",456)]
True
```

---

(You could equivalently use `traverse` or `traversed` instead of `each` here, they all traverse over the `Vector`; I just think `each` reads nicer.)